# moment.js get date format for input field placeholder

Tags: momentjs

I am using moment.js within an application. When a user logs into the application their locale is set:

```
moment.locale(userLocale);
```

I want to add a placeholder to an input field that represents the date format expected, based on the user's locale:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" />
```

Is there a way to get the string 'dd/mm/yyyy' from `moment`?

Comment: I want to get the actual format, i.e. the string `dd/mm/yyyy`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
moment(new Date()).localeData().longDateFormat('L').toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could access [locale specific functionality](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/) through

```
var currentLocaleData = moment.localeData();
```

Then it is possible to get full format of abbreviated date-time formats using `longDateFormat()` method:

```
var format = currentLocaleData.longDateFormat('L');
```

Comment: this is the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: @JoeTidee, yes, the answers are similar. But I worked from my phone and it requires more time than answer from a desktop. Thus, I hadn't seen second answer when created own. Moreover, my answer refers to original documentation, and there was no accepted answers when my answer had published.

Comment: No need to get defensive, simply remove your answer.